# I do not have use/local/src/ on Mac, what should I do?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, configure, aspell

I am neophyte on Mac especially on terminal. Though I've read lots of materials, I am still very confused and do not know what I should do.

I need to use aspell on MAC. I followed a tutorial (**http://wiki.lyx.org/Mac/MacSpelling**) to install it and I've installed Xcode and gcc. In one step, it required me to "type ./configure, followed by ". I did it, but terminal showed:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

This webpage (**http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1849525**) showed the configure in under "/usr/local/src/configure" but when I cd to this directory I found I do not have the /src/ folder.

```
/usr/local$ ls
CODEOFCONDUCT.md  README.md         include/          opt/
CONTRIBUTING.md   SUPPORTERS.md     info/             share/
Cellar/           bin/              lib/
LICENSE.txt       etc/              libexec/
Library/          git/              man/
```

What show I do? How can I use the ./configure?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [aspell-0.60.6.1 tarball](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/aspell-0.60.6.1.tar.gz) does have a `configure` script *inside* its own source tree (so it is located at `aspell-0.60.6.1/configure`). So you should start with something like (to do *outside* of `/usr/local/`, for example in your `$HOME/freesoftsource/` directory if you have one, or maybe even simply in your `$HOME` if you dare).

```
  wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/aspell-0.60.6.1.tar.gz
  tar xzvf aspell-0.60.6.1.tar.gz
  cd aspell-0.60.6.1
  ./configure
```

You may want to add some options to the `./configure` above.

You should read [aspell installing instructions](http://aspell.net/man-html/Installing.html)

<sup>N.B. As with most GNU software using `configure`, the location of the *source tree* (extracted from the source tar archive as above) does not matter much.</sup>

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!!! It really helps me a lot and makes me understand something. I do appreciate your help! Thanks again. Regards Chen.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. When I $ make $ make install, it shows some error (18 errors and 19 errors respectively.) It is normal? Or should I install some other packages and setting my environment?

Comment: You should install the dependencies. Perhaps ask on a MacOS specific forum.

Comment: I solved it by `brew install aspell`. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You likely don't have the command line development tools installed.

Try

xcode-select --install

It also looks like you have homebrew installed. I believe that there is a formula for aspell, so you can try

brew install aspell

Comment: I tried to install command line, but I did not find in in the preference/download under the Xcode 5.1.1 on OS X 10.9. There is only IOS6.1 Simulator in "Components"

Comment: One is not **supposed** to have to install the full XCode to get the command line tools. However, you can get it as a free download from the App store. The way it is supposed to work is that if you type a command that requires the command line tools (like `gcc`) it is **supposed** to prompt you to download them. Let us know how it works out.

Comment: I download the Xcode from the apple store and installed it. It is good. But I found as I am installing ASPELL, after `$ make $ make install`, terminal shows some error (18 errors and 19 errors respectively.) Is it normal? Or should I install some other packages and setting my environment?

Comment: That is why I suggested homebrew. The formulas have been tuned with the appropriate parameters for ./configure. (There are patches for `aspell.h`) Try `brew install aspell` It installed without errors on my MacBook Pro with Mavericks.

Comment: Yes, it works well. I found dictionaries of aspell cannot install by `brew install aspell --lang=en` but the traditional way works well. Anyway I've installed it now. Thank you for all your help and I do appreciate it. Regards